# Getting {"statusCode":404,"message":"Cannot GET /index.html","error":"Not Found"} on Electron JS on windows

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am using [This Boilerplate](https://github.com/alexdevero/electron-react-webpack-boilerplate) to create an Electron JS App. I have used this in the past too. I am facing the error `{"statusCode":404,"message":"Cannot GET /index.html","error":"Not Found"}` when running the app on windows.
Any idea why I am getting this error?
[image]

Comment: Can you give us more information? show us your file structure and your main electron js file please

Comment: I have attached a link to a boilerplate from where you can see almost everything. I have researched about this issue and came to know that this builds a dist folder at runtime and serve files from that folder. In my one PC it works but not in other folder. It doesn't create a dist folder.